# Alias for keeping feature branch in sync with "develop" branch

Tags: windows, git, bash, msysgit, git-config

I did few searches and found this alias to keep feature branch in sync with develop branch which works when I run from Git bash manually.

```
sync='!f() { echo Syncing this branch with develop && git checkout develop && 
git pull && git checkout – && git rebase develop; }; f'
```

I tried putting this alias in .gitconfig however I'm getting the following error

```
error: pathspec '"\342\200\223"' did not match any file(s) known to git.
```

what I found is git checkout -, which stands for, go back to last branch you were on creates this error.

I also tried putting the same command in .bashrc like below

```
alias sync='echo Syncing this branch with develop && git checkout develop && git pull 
&& git checkout – && git rebase develop'
```

which creates same error.

However just to make sure when I run all the commands in Git Bash manually they all work fine, so there is no other problem. Seems this is just because of differences in msysgit or bash on windows as I've read these alias work for git on mac and Linux.

Can some enlightened mind tell me how to change it to make it works on windows?

Thanks

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`\342\200\223` is an octal character sequence representing the [UTF-8 
"en dash" character](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/2013/index.htm):  octal `342 200 223` is the same as hex `e2 80 93`. You probably copy/pasted that command line from somewhere and that character is blowing `git`'s mind.  Use an ASCII `-`.

That is to say, this character: `–` and this one: `-` are *not the same*.  You need to use the latter.

You can check by running the character through your favourite hex dump program.  Here's my example:

```
$ echo -n – | hexdump
0000000 e2 80 93                                       
0000003
$ echo -n - | hexdump
0000000 2d                                             
0000001
```

Comment: You are so correct, sir. I did copy paste that line and when I used to type in Git bash manually it used to work. I just deleted - from .bashrc file and typed it manually, now it works. Thanks so much.